# Как отправить данные с сайта на две почты?

Tags: php, email

Есть такой код, и отправка сообщений происходит на **spr@domen.pro** нормально.Как правильно поправить функции чо бы добавить еще одного получателя **admin@email** Выполнил код как в статье [Отправка почты средствами PHP](https://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail), данные вообще не приходят

```js
<?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest')
{ 
  die('Error: Request error [1]');
}

// replace your_mail@your_domain.com with your E-mail address:
$my_email="spr@domen.pro";
$my_email_to = "spr@domen.pro";
$my_email.="admin@gmail.com";
$my_email_to .= "admin@gmail.com";

// change the text below for your Auto-Reply message:
$autoreply_subject = "Заявка";
$autoreply_message = "Спасибо за заявку! Мы свяжемся с вами" . "\n\n" .
             "С уважением, woodpuzzle.";

// request data on form submit
$sName = (isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["name"]) : false);
$sPhone = (isset($_REQUEST["phone"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["phone"]) : false);
$sComment = (isset($_REQUEST["comment"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["comment"]) : false);
$sIndex = (isset($_REQUEST["index"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["index"]) : false);
$sDelivery = (isset($_REQUEST["delivery"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["delivery"]) : false);
$sButton = (isset($_REQUEST["admin-data"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["admin-data"]) : false);
$sRadiob = (isset($_REQUEST["radiob"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["radiob"]) : false);


  



$headers = 'From: ' . $my_email . "\r\n" .
       'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $my_email . "\r\n" .
       'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
// include sender IP and some other data in the message
$subscribe_message = "Поступила новая заявка: " . "\n\n" .
             
              "Выбор: " . ($sButton ? $sButton : ' ') . "\n" .
             "Имя клиента: " . ($sName ? $sName : ' ') . "\n" .
             "Телефон клиента: " . ($sPhone ? $sPhone : ' ') . "\n" .
             "Пожелания клиента: " . ($sComment ? $sComment : ' ') . "\n" .
             "Почтовый индекс: " . ($sIndex ? $sIndex : ' ') . "\n" .             
             "Адрес доставки: " . ($sDelivery  ? $sDelivery  : ' ') . "\n" .
             "Способ доставки: " . ($sRadiob  ? $sRadiob  : ' ') . "\n" .
            
 
// remove the backslashes from form fields

$subscribe_message = stripslashes($subscribe_message); 
 
// add a prefix in the subject line so that you know the email was sent from your web site
$subject = "[domen.pro] Поступила новая заявка от " . ($sName ? $sName : 'неизвестного человека');
$sender = $sName;

// if variables are set, send $subscribe_message to $my_email
if (isset($subscribe_message) and isset($sender)) {
    
    $result_sending = false;

    if (mail($my_email_to, $subject, $subscribe_message, $headers))
    {
      $result_sending = true;
    }

    if($result_sending){

      /*$f = @fopen('../xdata_076839748238/'.date('Y').'_'.date('m').'.txt', 'a+');

      if ($f)
      {
        fwrite($f, date('Y:m:d H:i:s')."\n"."Имя клиента: ".($sName ? $sName : '---')."\n"."Телефон клиента: ".$sPhone."\n\n");
        fclose($f);
      }*/

      echo 'sended';

      $num_orders_array = file('../../1.txt');
      $num_orders = 0;
      $new_num_orders = 1;

      if ($num_orders_array && sizeof($num_orders_array) > 0)
      {
        $num_orders = intval(trim($num_orders_array[0]));
        $new_num_orders = $num_orders+1;

        $f = fopen('../../1.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($f, strval($new_num_orders));
        fclose($f);
      }
      else
      {
        $f = fopen('../../1.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($f, strval($new_num_orders));
        fclose($f);
      }
        
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'problems_1';
    }
}
else
{
  echo 'problems_2';
}
?>
```

Comment: Нормально оформите вопрос и расскажите об ошибках, проблемах и т.п., которые возникают.

Comment: @n.osennij Так правильно оформлено?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$my_email="spr@domain.pro";
$my_emails_to =[
    "admin1@email",
    "admin2@email",
    "admin3@email",
];


foreach ($my_emails_to as $my_email_to) {

    if (isset($subscribe_message) and isset($sender) and sendEmail($my_email, $my_email_to)) {

        //Письмо отправлено
        //Вызов какой-то другой функции

    }

}


function sendEmail($from, $to, $subject = '', $subscribe_message = '', $headers = '')
{
    return mail($to, $subject, $subscribe_message, $headers); //А где $from, т.е. $my_email?
}
```

Comment: //А где $from, т.е. $my_email? в том то и дело, что нигде не указана, но на доменную почту сообщения приходят стабильно, а вот на админов не хотят приходить

Comment: так в хедеры пихайте - https://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail

Comment: Извиняюсь, изначально ввел Вас в заблуждение. В теле вопроса полностью вставил весь код, что бы было понятно, и небыло неразберихи

Comment: @n-osennij сделал как указано в статье, сообщения не приходят совсем

Comment: тогда вам сюда - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer